# MFC C++ Pointer to function newbie

Tags: c++, pointers, mfc

I have a solution with many projects.
I would like to make a class inside common project that receive array and pointer to function.
This class is a member in other projects on that solution. each project class can hold it as member.

On the constructor of the class inside common, How do i pass the pointer of the function ? how do i set a member inside the common class that holds the location of the function i would like to invoke later on ?

My goal is that i can invoke the function using the pointer - while im in the code of the class that is found in the common project..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On the constructor of the class inside common, How do i pass the
>   pointer of the function ? how do i set a member inside the common
>   class that holds the location of the function i would like to invoke
>   later on ?

```
typedef void(*FUNCPTR)(int);
```

This defines my function pointer type, but it also restricts the function to the signature below (retuens void and takes 1 int param) you need to define this for your function signature.

```
void myFunction( int someParam )
{
    //DoSomething with someParam
}


class Foo
{
private:
    FUNCPTR mFunction; //Holds pointer

public:
    Foo( FUNCPTR function) : mFunction(function) {} //Initialise instance

    void callFunc() {mFunction(1);} //call function
};

int main(unsigned int argc, const char** argv)
{
    Foo myFoo(myFunction);

    myFoo.callFunc();
}
```

In C++ you might well be better however thinking about using function objects in which you create an object and define an `operator()` which takes the correct parameters and return type but would allow you all the flexibility of objects and polymorphism....

See [C++ Functors - and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses) for some discussion and detail